# Reshaping object in arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, geometry, editing, cursor

I want to make a kind of Resape script tool for highlited polygons.
For example there are two polygons from different *.gdb files that share a same boundary and they need to be merged.
I read coordinates form the first shape then from the second and made a list of coordinates. Then united them into one list made an array with `arcpy.Point(x,y)` features. Finally, did `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` thing and got a new polygon with geometry of two polygons.
And is there any other way to do it with `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`?
For instance, using something like

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polygon_fc, "SHAPE@XY") as uc:
    for row in uc:
        p_obj = uc.getPart(0)
        #some stuff
        uc.updateRow(row) - #calculating "SHAPE" field to bring new coordinates from list of new points
```

I know that there is an easy way to make it manually through Merge tool, but anyway is it possible to do with a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have features selected, I'd just go for the Merge GP tool. Keep in mind that geoprocessing tools respect selections which means only selected features will be merged. You can then read the merged polygon(s) and you can create output using the `in_memory` geodatabase.

If you need to do more geometry analysis operations before the merge, I'd suggest looking the `arcpy.Geometry` [methods](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm#M1_GUID-BC466D06-360C-42BD-B198-DA4139B45F49) such as `union`.

```
>>> g1 = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("polys",'SHAPE@')][0]
>>> g2 = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("polys",'SHAPE@')][1]
>>> g1
<Polygon object at 0x2a4b5c90[0x2a4b5b60]>
>>> g2
<Polygon object at 0x2a4b5b90[0x2a4b5b40]>
>>> g1.union(g2)
<Polygon object at 0x22666130[0x226020a0]>
>>> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(g1.union(g2), 'merged')
<Result 'C:\\GIS\\Temp\\ArcGISHomeFolder\\Default.gdb\\merged'>
```

If you would like to replace these two polygons with the merged polygon, it's all about deleting the rows with the needed FIDs and then using `da.InsertCursor`. Alternatively, you can delete any of these two polys and replace the shape of the left one with the `SHAPE@` of the merged one using `da.UpdateCursor`.

Comment: that works! But what about changing the initial object, I mean UpdateCursor? I wanted to perform every operation within an initial feature class

Comment: Please refer to the answer - I've written how this is done.